# Looking for the most elegant solution for looping a specific string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, loops

so i got a dozen of strings which i download and one of the example is this one

"Australija      036 AUD    1        5,136250        5,151705        5,167160"

the spaces are shown as single here, but are actually multiple between the numbers and chars.

So my first idea was to count manually where the number i need is (the second one, 5.151705 in this example) and get substring.(41,8) but that seems ify to me.

Second idea was to save all the number like chars in a vector, and then get 
vector[4] and save it into a seperate variable.

And third one is to just loop the string until i position myself after the 5th group of spaces and then substring it.

Just looking for some feedback on what would be "best".

Comment: Is it always the second number? Are all the strings follow the same format? If yes, then either of first or second method will work. But if the answer is no, the best way is to loop through!

Comment: They will always be the same and always the second number.

Comment: Then it is a constant expression. You know what to read, and where in the string to read it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also think of first trimming multiple whitespace. Something like

```
std::string str = "Australija  036   AUD  1  5,136250  5,151705   5,167160";
str.erase(std::unique(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char a, char b) {
        return ::isspace(a) && ::isspace(b);
    }), str.end());
```

A string split may also be useful

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string & str, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::string token;
    while (getline(ss, token, delim)) result.push_back(token);
    return result;
}
```

and calling it

```
std::vector<std::string> result = split(str, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use streams for this task, as they swallow up multiple spaces in a graceful manner.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>


int main() {
  std::string line = "Australija  036   AUD  1  5,136250  5,151705   5,167160";

  // Extract string beginning
  std::istringstream input(line);
  std::string p1, p2, p3;
  int i1 = 0;
  input >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 >> i1;

  // Replace commas
  std::string double_numbers;
  std::getline(input, double_numbers);
  std::replace(double_numbers.begin(), double_numbers.end(), ',','.');

  // Extract the remaining numbers
  double d1 = 0, d2 = 0, d3=0;
  std::istringstream(double_numbers) >> d1 >> d2 >> d3;

  // Print result
  std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << d2 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a bit overkill, since i can do the parsing (badly) with just one line of code with substring. But appreciate the effort and the idea! ill keep the streams in mind for further coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string str="abc   def ghi   1234 5.123";
    stringstream ss(str);
    string token;
    int i=0;
    while(ss>>token ){
        if(i==4){
        printf("%s\n",token.c_str());
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/miJcoY)